# Error reading entity from input stream Dropwizard example

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I'm attempting to use this [dropwizard example](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example) and build off of it. I tried to add a column `userName` to the `people` table in [Person.java](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/core/Person.java) like below

```
public class Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "fullName", nullable = false)
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "jobTitle", nullable = false)
private String jobTitle;

@Column(name = "userName", nullable = false)
private String userName;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String fullName, String jobTitle, String userName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

I added the appropriate getters and setters, and equals method.

However I'm getting an error reading entity from input stream in this block.

```
@Test
public void testPostPerson() throws Exception {
    final Person person = new Person("Dr. IntegrationTest", "Chief Wizard", "Dr. Wizard");
    final Person newPerson = RULE.client().target("http://localhost:" + RULE.getLocalPort() + "/people")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
     -->    .readEntity(Person.class);
    assertThat(newPerson.getId()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(newPerson.getFullName()).isEqualTo(person.getFullName());
    assertThat(newPerson.getJobTitle()).isEqualTo(person.getJobTitle());
    assertThat(newPerson.getUserName()).isEqualTo(person.getUserName());
}
```

the input stream error is caused by the following

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
Unrecognized field "code" (class com.example.helloworld.core.Person), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "fullName", "id", "userName", "jobTitle"])
```

will `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation at the class level solve this problem? Is this safe practice?

EDIT: `PersonResource.java`

```
@Path("/people/{personId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource {

private final PersonDAO peopleDAO;

public PersonResource(PersonDAO peopleDAO) {
    this.peopleDAO = peopleDAO;
}

@GET
@UnitOfWork
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
    return findSafely(personId.get());
}

@GET
@Path("/view_freemarker")
@UnitOfWork
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public PersonView getPersonViewFreemarker(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
    return new PersonView(PersonView.Template.FREEMARKER, findSafely(personId.get()));
}

@GET
@Path("/view_mustache")
@UnitOfWork
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public PersonView getPersonViewMustache(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
    return new PersonView(PersonView.Template.MUSTACHE, findSafely(personId.get()));
}

private Person findSafely(long personId) {
    return peopleDAO.findById(personId).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("No such user."));
}
```

Comment: Can you quote your resource method? It seems that the request is getting an invalid response instead of a Person object.

Comment: updated @CanBican

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the resource fails and throws a web application exception and code is actually the http status code.

Try it like this:

```
Response response = RULE.client().target("http://localhost:" + RULE.getLocalPort() + "/people")
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
Person newPerson = response.readEntity(Person.class);
....
```

You may also debug like this:

```
String responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Which will dump you the body of the response.

Comment: hmmm this is the outcome of the changes `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<500>`

Comment: I thought you were asking about serialization problems, so I stopped there :) You don't have a method annotated with @POST so if you haven't skipped it in your question, that's the problem. You need some method that can handle post queries for this particular test to be successful.